# Removing session attribute in jsp portlet issue in liferay

Tags: java, jsp, session, liferay, portlet

After passing data to another portlet through session if want to clear that `sessionAttribute` at the destination portlet but it doesn't work.

In destination portlet I get the session attribute and clear it, but after refreshing the JSP page. The session attribute is still there. It should be `null`. How can I get rid of that as the following code not working.

```jsp
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<%@page import="javax.portlet.PortletSession" %>
<portlet:defineObjects />

This is the <b>NewPPIPC</b> portlet in View mode.

<%

PortletSession ps = renderRequest.getPortletSession();
String qString = (String)ps.getAttribute("sessionValue",PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
ps.removeAttribute("sessionValue");

%>

<h1><%=qString %></h1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overloaded method uses `PORTLET_SCOPE` to search for the object, but you need to specify a scope `APPLICATION_SCOPE`.

```
ps.removeAttribute("sessionValue", PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
```